# How to send GET/POST parameter to a page via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, errordocument

I want to  redirect to error page if the requested URI comes up with the 500 error.
I did some thing like this:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /Errors/500.php?p=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

to send to "500.php" the requested uri as a GET param to handle the request. But the 500.php does not receive the GET param.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** in your php file.
e.g.

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

should show the link, the user requested.

Answer (score 0):

"500.php" won't get any parameter because you are calling 505.php

did you try `phpinfo(32);` by the way? I am pretty sure you have your request already, with no additional parameters.